# formatted xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

i am using following code to create xml file using php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $doc->formatOutput = true;

        $root = $doc->createElement('alerts');
        $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

        $alert = $doc->createElement('alert');
        $alert = $root->appendChild($alert);

        $id = $doc->createElement('id');
        $id_text = $doc->createTextNode($api_id);
        $id->appendChild($id_text);
        $alert->appendChild($id);

        $msg_type = $doc->createElement('msg_type');
        $msg_type_text = $doc->createTextNode(1);
        $msg_type->appendChild($msg_type_text);
        $alert->appendChild($msg_type);
$doc->save($filename);
```

it saves xml file well formatted like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<alerts>
  <alert>
    <id>22</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
  </alert>
 </alerts>
```

but when i append tags in existing file with following code it will not formatted

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->formatOutput = true;

            $xml = file_get_contents($filename);
            $doc->loadXML($xml);


            $root = $doc->firstChild;

            $alert = $doc->createElement('alert');
            $alert = $root->appendChild($alert);

            $id = $doc->createElement('id');
            $id_text = $doc->createTextNode($api_id);
            $id->appendChild($id_text);
            $alert->appendChild($id);

            $msg_type = $doc->createElement('msg_type');
            $msg_type_text = $doc->createTextNode(1);
            $msg_type->appendChild($msg_type_text);
            $alert->appendChild($msg_type);
$doc->save($filename);
```

xml file format will be like this

```
<alerts>
  <alert>
    <id>3</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Api Name:Loop LM (H-PO) has low credit.</msg>
    <url>common/api/view_sms_api_list.php</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1387351877</create_date>
  </alert>
<alert><id>6</id><msg_type>1</msg_type></alert><alert><id>14</id><msg_type>1</msg_type></alert><alert><id>24</id><msg_type>1</msg_type></alert></alerts>
```

it will continue in single line when i append a alert tag in this xml file. what is the problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: $doc->formatOutput = true; should work... But normally I'll set it right before save().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` before load your doc `$doc->loadXML($xml);`